# how you may obtain the prime factors of m and n without using the method of prime factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-factorization

Let p, q and r be distinct odd primes. Suppose n = pq and m = pr. Given that you know that m and n share a common prime factor, but that you do not know the values of p, q, r, explain how you may obtain the prime factors of m and n without using the method of prime factorization?

Can someone help me start this?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: What's the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: p is, but how does that help?

Comment: @albert Well, taking gcd's is very easy by the Euclidean algorithm. And once you know one prime factor of $pq$, you know the other.

Comment: sorry, im still not following. so we have gcd (m,n) = p. By EEA, we  have mx+ny=p, how does this help?

Comment: @albert So without using any factorization algorithm, you've found $p$. That's what you were looking for.

Comment: so when you know one of the prime factors then you can just divide n by p and get q?

Comment: @albert Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Since p, q and r are all primes the only common factor of n and m is p.

So we can use the greatest common divisor algorithm (which for large numbers is *much* easier than prime factorisation) to find p. Then it is a simple matter of division to find q and r.

Furthermore there is a trick that allows this approach to be scaled to large numbers of inputs without having to compute each pairwise gcd individually. See section 3.3 https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.conference.pdf